# GZIP not working in Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to load compressed javascript and css files on my page. My files are in the amazon s3 server and I have configured the Cloudfront Distribution to Compress Objects Automatically. Even after setting up the Cloudfront Distribution, I am still getting the uncompressed files on my page instead of the compressed ones that Cloudfront should be loading.

[image]

Files in my Amazon s3 server

https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/02242017-bucket1/animate.css

https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/02242017-bucket1/jssor.js

My Request Header reads

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Referer:http://test.sitepm.com/simplewebcontent/710/1/peterspage1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

My Response Header is

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:58701
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Tue, 28 Feb 2017 10:30:41 GMT
ETag:"be74d5befb57a55bcf71d5af775f8dfb"
Last-Modified:Fri, 24 Feb 2017 05:06:32 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:ioAxulBZpyxcqCAdvQ47uCuA2zwvh9wrUXA6yyPdL0dt9suwZWSHc8E0hrxte+cBd8kpQt4IYEI=
x-amz-request-id:1FA844B6044B1E2A
```

My Cloudfront Origin Settings
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have configured a CloudFront distribution, but based on these request and response headers, you're not actually requesting the objects through CloudFront.

Request:

```
Host:s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

This is obviously not a CloudFront hostname, e.g. `dxxxexample.cloudfront.net`, and not a hostname from a custom domain... You're requesting this directly from S3.

Response:

If this request had been processed by CloudFront, the response headers `Via` and `X-Cache`  and `X-Amz-Cf-Id` would be present, but they are not.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about "Domain Name d3djkdfiadimdg.cloudfront.net". If so, how would my file urls be?

Comment: `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/02242017-bucket1/jssor.js` would become `https://d3djkdfiadimdg.cloudfront.net/jssor.js`.

Comment: I agree @Stuborg, but if your CloudFront configuration were correct, that URL would also be correct.  Please tell me what you have set for the origin host and origin path.

Comment: I have added my origin settings in the question

Comment: Remove the origin path.  That's used to inject a prefix you want added to each request URI between CloudFront and S3, and is rarely used.  Remember to wait for the distribution to transition back to "Deployed" and test again.

Comment: The origin path was the issue. I removed it and the URLs are working now. Thanks a lot.